# Usage of var in CSS3

Tags: css

I have stumbled upon this [pen](https://codepen.io/electerious/pen/rroqdL).

In it's code there are fragments using `var(--tx, 0)`

Then variable `--tx` is referenced and set in JS via

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--tx', 'valueForProperty');
```

I searched google, mdn etc. and found out css3 variables. But what I understood, about them, is that one declares variables in `:root` pseudo element then use them with `var` keyword ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)).
I didn't find information about second variable to var. I guess `var(name, value)` initializes variable in place, yet I couldn't replicate this in my pen. 
The original author uses SCSS preprocesor, it might be the catch, but it declares variables with `$` sign.

So I ask if somebody can explain, what's going on in this [pen](https://codepen.io/electerious/pen/rroqdL) in regards to `var` statements.

Comment: You don't *have* to specify them in `:root`. Doing so just makes them available globally. The second value is supposedly a [fall-back](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#using-variables). But I dunno how that works.

Comment: @AnkithAmtange Author of the pen doesn't "declare" any variables before using them in transforms. Yet they are set on document.documentElement styles which is <html> in DOM. What is strange for me I can't replicate this on my pen ...

Comment: He sets these custom properties in JavaScript and uses them in CSS for `transform` _with a fallback_ as noted by @AnkithAmtange (thanks for the info, never heard of that fallback!). As he's setting and modifying these "variables" (custom properties) in events, it's something CSS can't do `:root { --rx: 0; }` is static

Comment: @AnkithAmtange The link you provided shows in Example 10 how this fallback can be used. Something like "if custom property not defined (neither on :root nor in scope of element), then use this fallback value"

Comment: @FelipeAls Now  I see it. I don't know why I fixed myself on thought that css sets variables and JS just fils them containers. Thank You All